# "The Midwest of the U.S."

Tags: capitalization, toponyms

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* reports the following definition for *Middle America*:

> Middle America |ˈˌmɪdl əˈmɛrəkə|
>   noun
>   1 the middle class in the U.S., esp. when regarded as a conservative political force.
>   • the Midwest of the U.S.
>   2 the North American region that includes Mexico and Central America, and often the West Indies.
>   DERIVATIVES
>   Middle American noun
>   Middle-American adjective

Why is *Midwest* in *the Midwest of the U.S.* written capitalized?

Compare it with the following definition given for *northeast*:

> adjective
>   1 lying toward, near, or facing the northeast.
>   • (of a wind) coming from the northeast: *there was a strong northeast wind*.
>   2 of or denoting the northeastern part of a specified country, region, or town, or its inhabitants: *northeast Baltimore*.

In *northeast Baltimore*, *northeast* is not capitalized. What is the difference between the two cases?

When I write *Middle American* to mean an American person of the middle class, why cannot I write *middle American*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between northeast Baltimore and Middle America is that "Middle America" is the name of a particular notion that has extra connotations outside of just the fact that it is in the middle of America.  As you can see, it carries with it the concept of the middle class and conservative ideas.  So, this whole phrase is the name of a thing that is greater than the sum of its parts, and it is capitalized.  The northeast of Baltimore, on the other hand, is not the name of a specific region in the sense of being defined and carrying any extra meaning.

This happens all over the place.  If I talk about living in east St. Louis (and the reader knows I am not being careless in my capitalization), then they would assume I probably mean the eastern region of the city of St. Louis.  But if I say I live in East St. Louis, then they know that is the name of a different town located next to St. Louis, in a different state.

Answer (score 5):

*Midwest* is a proper noun in that context, so it must be capitalized. Unlike *northeast*, it is not a standard direction; it is referring to a specific region of the U.S.

*Northeast* is both a direction and [a region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regions_of_the_United_States#Interstate_regions). When it is a direction, it is not capitalized unless it is used as part of a proper name.

[*Middle America*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_class#Middle_America) is a proper name, thus both words are capitalized. *The middle of America* would not be capitalized.

Answer (score -2):

Midwest is definetly a proper noun. At first I thought it was a common noun but I looked in my book and I found that Midwest is used a lot for terms like "I live in the Midwest" or something like that. It is used to tell where something is in the Midwest. What I am trying to say is, Midwest is a region, not a direction.

Comment: Everything in this answer is already there in the two existing answers. Answers to questions should provide new, relevant information. Also, we like sourced and referenced answers here that give the answerer some weight behind their words, and “I looked in my book” is not a reference.

Comment: I don't think I worded this correctly! I get what you are saying but I could not think of anything else to say.

Comment: I am very sorry if I upset you if you are trying to figure out if Midwest is a common or proper noun. Let me redo that sentence. At first I thought it was a common noun but then I looked through my resources that my teacher gave me (grammarisfun.com) and looked up if it was common or proper. I quickly found that is was proper. Janus Bahs Jacquet, I am very sorry I did not say "Ilooked in my book" particularly. Did I say book in the answer? I meant website. I am very sorry for the confusion. Hopefully I will answer more questions. Correctly this time! Look out for my name whenever you are on!!!

Comment: @Cia. This is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site which has specific guidelines for participation. If you have not done so already, I strongly encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance.